# Function expression hoisting?

Tags: javascript

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/el/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

"Function expressions in JavaScript are not hoisted, unlike function declarations. You can't use function expressions before you declare them."

Example:

```
var hey = function(){
    console.log("hi");
}
```

Chrome's console: window.hey returns

```
function (){
console.log("hi");
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I don't see any question here, pls make clear what you want to know.

Comment: What's the question? You're using `window.hey` **after** you declare the function, so the dociumentation you quoted doesn't apply.

Comment: I guess the word "hoisting" is unclear to him. `function x()` can be called even prior to its declaration, while `var x = function()` is not available until it's defined.

Comment: Yea..I messed it up in my head.Got it now.

Answer (score 1):

What it's saying is that you can't write:

```
hey();
var hey = function() {
    console.log("hi");
}
```

because you're using the variable `hey` before you assign the function expression to it. But you *can* write:

```
hey();
function hey() {
    console.log("hi");
}
```

because function declarations are hoisted to the beginning of the containing function.

For more information, see [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn)

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Barmar's answer, when you do:

```
hey();
var hey = function() {
    console.log("hi");
}
```

technically the variable declaration is still hoisted, but the assignment remains where it is written, so it is equivalent to:

```
var hey;
hey(); // hey is declared as a variable, but is still undefined.
hey = function() {
    console.log("hi");
}
```