# Which function is executed if both has same variable names n declared?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, let

```
let foo = function(){
    console.log(1);
}
setTimeout (foo,1000);

foo = function(){
    console.log(2);
}
```

I got the output as 1. But I need to know why because let can be reinitialized so its correct over here why didn't I get the o/p as 2?

Comment: Works as intended: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000) JS doesn't track changes to the variable *after* the value has been read. It's the same situation as `let x = 1; console.log(x); x = 2;`  - the value `1` has been read and used. Won't shift into a `2` for code which has already been executed.

Comment: You’re passing *the function* to `setTimeout`, not the variable name or the variable.

Comment: but here function is invoked using variable foo right ? so foo is a variable or not

Comment: @sujithrakumaran — No, that isn't how it is invoked. Yes, foo is a variable. The function is invoked by reading the reference to it from the variable `foo` and passing that reference to `setTimeout` (and then the internals of `setTimeout` take over and it gets invoked a second later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second variable is not declared when run this line `setTimeout (foo,1000);`  you can check it by commenting the `let foo = function(){ console.log(1); }`

Comment: aint javascript follows hoisting ? so why `let foo = function(){ console.log(2); }`  cant be hoisted?

Comment: @sujithrakumaran — The values of function declarations are hoisted, that's a function expression.

Comment: @sujithrakumaran hoisting has no relation to the code you've showed. See [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859) | [Why do function declarations get hoisted and function expressions don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57799578) | [Function expression hoisting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42615693)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).